# Django, filter by specified month and year in date range

Tags: python, django

I have the following models

```
class Destination_Deal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Nombre"),max_length=200)

class Departure_Date(models.Model):
    date_from= models.DateField(_('Desde'))    
    date_to= models.DateField(_('Hasta'))
    destination_deal = models.ForeignKey(Destination_Deal,verbose_name = _("Oferta de Destino"))
```

This is the actual data in the table departure_date

```
id  date_from   date_to     destination_deal_id
1   2012-11-01  2013-03-17  1
2   2012-11-01  2012-12-16  2
3   2012-09-16  2012-10-31  3
4   2012-11-01  2012-12-16  3
5   2013-01-04  2013-01-11  4
```

I would like to filter the Destination_Deals if a specified month&year is between date_from and date_to.

**Example 1**

> Month: September (09)
> Year: 2012

**Wanted departure dates result:**
ID 3 : It is the only data range that touch 09/2012

**Example 2**

> Month: February (02)
> Year: 2013

**Wanted departure dates result:**
ID 1 : 02/2012 is before 03/2012

So, the day actually is does not matter. If the month&year is between date_from and date_to, even if it is by one day it must be filter.

I think I must use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664636/django-date-filter-by-day-of-month?answertab=votes#tab-top) but I am not sure how to do it.

**---Edit---**
This is the test for the answer from Aamir Adnan but it is not working as I expected as ID 1 must be also returned because it goes from November 2012 to March 2013, so January 2013 is between.

```
Departure_Date.objects.all()
[<Departure_Date: id: 1 - from: 2012-11-01 - to: 2013-03-17>,
<Departure_Date: id: 2 - from: 2012-11-01 - to: 2012-12-16>,
<Departure_Date: id: 3 - from: 2012-09-16 - to: 2012-10-31>,
<Departure_Date: id: 4 - from: 2012-11-01 - to: 2012-12-16>,
<Departure_Date: id: 5 - from: 2013-01-04 - to: 2013-01-11>]


month:1
year:2013
where = '%(year)s >= YEAR(date_from) AND %(month)s >= MONTH(date_from) \
    AND %(year)s <= YEAR(date_to) AND %(month)s <= MONTH(date_to)' % \
    {'year': year, 'month': month}
Departure_Date.objects.extra(where=[where])
[<Departure_Date: id: 5 - from: 2013-01-04 - to: 2013-01-11>]
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year)

```
year = 2012
month = 09
Departure_Date.objects.filter(date_from__year__gte=year,
                              date_from__month__gte=month,
                              date_to__year__lte=year,
                              date_to__month__lte=month)
```

Alternative method using `.extra`:

```
where = '%(year)s >= YEAR(date_from) AND %(month)s >= MONTH(date_from) \
        AND %(year)s <= YEAR(date_to) AND %(month)s <= MONTH(date_to)' % \
        {'year': year, 'month': month}
Departure_Date.objects.extra(where=[where])
```

There is a specific case where above query does not yield a desired result.

For example:

```
date_from='2012-11-01'
date_to='2013-03-17'
and input is
year=2013
month=1
```

Then `%(month)s >= MONTH(date_from)` condition is wrong because month 1 is < month 11 in `date_from` but year is different so MySQL `IF` condition is required here:

```
where = '%(year)s >= YEAR(date_from) AND IF(%(year)s > YEAR(date_from), \
     IF(%(month)s > MONTH(date_from), %(month)s >= MONTH(date_from), %(month)s < MONTH(date_from)), \
     IF(%(month)s < MONTH(date_from), %(month)s < MONTH(date_from), %(month)s >= MONTH(date_from))) \
     AND %(year)s <= YEAR(date_to) \
     AND %(month)s <= MONTH(date_to)' % \
     {'year': year, 'month': month}
Departure_Date.objects.extra(where=[where])
```

Comment: I got the following error: "FieldError: Join on field 'date_to' not permitted. Did you misspell 'month' for the lookup type?" AFAIK it is not possible to mix suffixes or I am wrong?

Comment: That is strange, I know that on dates extended lookups (e.g. year, month) `__in` is not permitted. Please check the alternative method in my answer. Thanks

Comment: Now I get "DatabaseError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MONTH(date_from) >= 12 YEAR(date_to) <= 2012 MONTH(date_to) <= 12 LIMIT 21' at line 1")". Is there any other way without "extra" to keep it database independent and using Destination_Deals instead of Departure_Date?

Comment: Thanks. I already tried with "and" but it is not what I asked for. Did you tried with the example data? Another example, Month:1 - Year:2013. Results must be ID 1 and ID 5. Also I would like to avoid using extra if it is possible.

Comment: Please test it again and let me know if it is not doing what you have asked for. I have updated the query and I have tested it on your data and it is working fine. Please copy the query I have posted again.

Comment: Hello. Ok, I just edited the question with the test of your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Q-Protex I have updated the answer with another query. Please read details and reason why My query did't work and why the new query should work. Thanks!

Comment: @Q-Protex Please test with the latest query, query is updated again and tested.

Comment: @AamirAdnan I think you put the lte and get in wrong places

Answer (score 5):

Solution using python code only. Main idea is to construct date_from and date_to with python. Then these dates can be used in `filter` with `__lte` and `__gte`:

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime
from django.db.models import Q

def in_month_year(month, year):
    d_fmt = "{0:>02}.{1:>02}.{2}"
    date_from = datetime.strptime(
        d_fmt.format(1, month, year), '%d.%m.%Y').date()
    last_day_of_month = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
    date_to = datetime.strptime(
        d_fmt.format(last_day_of_month, month, year), '%d.%m.%Y').date()
    return Departure_Date.objects.filter(
        Q(date_from__gte=date_from, date_from__lte=date_to)
         |
        Q(date_from__lt=date_from, date_to__gte=date_from))
```

Now this will work:

```
>>> Departure_Date.objects.all()
[<Departure_Date: id: 1 - from: 2012-11-01 - to: 2013-03-17>,
<Departure_Date: id: 2 - from: 2012-11-01 - to: 2012-12-16>,
<Departure_Date: id: 3 - from: 2012-09-16 - to: 2012-10-31>,
<Departure_Date: id: 4 - from: 2012-11-01 - to: 2012-12-16>,
<Departure_Date: id: 5 - from: 2013-01-04 - to: 2013-01-11>]


>>> in_month_year(month=1, year=2013)
[<Departure_Date: id: 1 - from: 2012-11-01 - to: 2013-03-17>,
<Departure_Date: id: 5 - from: 2013-01-04 - to: 2013-01-11>]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get around the "impedance mismatch" caused by the lack of precision in the `DateTimeField/date` object comparison -- that can occur if using **range** -- by using a **datetime.timedelta** to add a day to last date in the range. This works like:

```
import datetime

start = date(2012, 12, 11)
end = date(2012, 12, 18)
new_end = end + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

ExampleModel.objects.filter(some_datetime_field__range=[start, new_end])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 filters with `__gte` and `__lte`:

```py
import datetime as dt

start = dt.date(2012, 12, 11)
end = dt.date(2012, 12, 18)
ExampleModel.objects.filter(date_field__gte=start).filter(date_field__lte=end)
```